# Changing default startup directory for command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt

How do I change default startup directory for command prompt in Windows 7?

I usually do the following to start command prompt from C:\

```
  WIN-R (Run Prompt)
  cmd /K cd C:\
```

I want to do the following to start command prompt from C:\

```
  WIN-R (Run Prompt)
  cmd
```

Comment: Superuser.com might be better suited for this question.

Comment: I found the least system invasive solution here http://superuser.com/a/155863/12735

Comment: There's another good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485003/5016547

Comment: Have you tried using the `set` command inside CMD to see the variables that are available?  Or considered using something like `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K "cd targetdirectory"` as your shortcut?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While adding a [AutoRun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439(WS.10).aspx) entry to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` like Shinnok's answer is the way to go [it can also really mess things up](https://web.archive.org/web/20100603221913/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx), you really should try to detect a simple cmd.exe startup vs a script/program using cmd.exe as a child process:

```
IF /I x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)
```

Comment: you can use this command from the command line `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)"`

Comment: Just a note... I did this and while running any command-line functions such as `grunt` or `bower` it will attempt to use THIS directory rather than the directory you are currently in... Just an FYI

Comment: I got similar breakage with Heroku's command line tools, resulting in its interactions with `git` failing silently. This solution might not be worth the headache depending on what tools you use.

Comment: I ran into a case mismatch issue with this.  Had to modify the line slightly to get it to work.  /I to add case insensitivity.  The issue was with c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

    `IF /I x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)`

Comment: how to make it so that it also works when you run cmd as administrator.. with the "run as" option

Comment: @venimus put your comment reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)" as answer, it worked for me

Comment: @AlexCurvers for run as admin check https://superuser.com/questions/1067901/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-a-specific-folder-as-administrator

Comment: I use

`reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF /i x"%USERPROFILE%""%COMSPEC%"==x"%CD%"%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /d c:\)"` which additionally checks for the default working directory (seems to be %USERPROFILE%). This should avoid most problems when cmd ist called from other tools.

Answer (score 105):

Make a shortcut pointing to cmd.exe somwhere (e.g. desktop) then right-click on the copy and select "properties". Navigate to the "Shortcut" menu and change the "Start in:" directory.

Comment: This worked for me, if you want to start in C:\ just add "\" and not "c:\" otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: That is pretty much what I did. Much safer and cleaner. BUT like @Cerveser does not appear to work if you run as admin.

Comment: Just to add, this way you can have multiple cmd shortcuts each pointing to a different startup directory.

Comment: running as administrator goes to system 32 =(

Comment: you don't need to make a shortcut - there is already one you can edit. See answer by @BenOcc - although the path on win10 is slightly different

Answer (score 52):

The following solution worked well for me.  Navigate to the command prompt shortcut in the start menu:

C:\Users\ *your username* \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Command Prompt

Right click on the shortcut file to open the properties dialog.  Inside the "Start in:" textbox you should see %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.  If you want the prompt to start in C:\ just replace the variables with "C:\" (without quotes).

***update***

It appears that Microsoft has changed this behavior recently and so now an additional step is required.  After performing the steps above copy the modified shortcut "Command Prompt" and rename it to "cmd".  Then when typing "cmd" in the start menu it should once again work.

Comment: On my Win 8.1, I found the shortcut under `Windows System`, not Accessories.

Comment: Good answer -- works, no hacks required, won't break other tools.

Comment: For users using multiple command line interfaces,(GIT BASH, CYGWIN, Language Shells) This is the safest answer. You can even assign the shortcut to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Though, I'm still doing "Win+R > Enter" ("cmd" being already input, as the remembered last entry). So I put a `cmddesk.cmd` file in my PATH: `@CMD /K CD /D <startup dir>`. I just have to remember typing "cmddesk" instead of "cmd" when it's not in the Win+R box.

Comment: On my Windows 10, the cmd shortcut is located in "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System"

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! In Windows 10 it seems that the step under "update" is not necessary.

Answer (score 42):

Open regedit and browse to this path

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Create new string vale named `Autorun`. Set its value to `cd /d C:\`.

Run cmd again. Voila!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will cause problems since scripts and other programs might launch cmd.exe/%comspec% and end up in the wrong directory!

Comment: @Anders, yes, you are right, pretty much every invocation of cmd from there on will start on C:, which could potentially break some functionality for scripts and other tools making use of cmd.

Comment: <del>could potentially break some functionality</del> <ins>will certainly break to the ground a vast amount of scripts</ins>

Comment: Doing this will ultimately result in suffering.

Comment: I'm a lazy guy. So i need default on C: volume is "c:\folder_name". And then i switch to D: volume, default is "d:\other_folder_name". Can i get it?

Comment: Completely forgot that I followed this advice, and spent COUNTLESS hours trying to debug why npm and nodemon were failing.  Please don't do this.

Comment: Don't do this ! That fails when i'm using `npm run ...` and probably in another programs.

Comment: This answer should probably be removed. Similarly wasted hours trying to fix issues with far manager before realizing this was the cause. Every command would execute from C:\, for example C:\directory>cd would return C:\.

Comment: I've also had this configuration for months, it worked without me noticing until others mentioned, that certain npm/node cmds stopped working correctly. I quickly caught on, though, because it was throwing weird errors with accessing System32, the root path, or not having permission. Ideally, npm should warn you about this though.

Answer (score 26):

## Easiest way to do this

1. Click "Start" and type "cmd" or "command prompt".
2. Select Top most search application named exactly same "cmd" or "command prompt".
3. Right Click on it and select "Send To"=>"Desktop".
4. On Your Desktop New "cmd" Shortcut will appear
5. Right Click on that icon and choose "properties"
6. Popup will appear, In "Shortcut" Tab Type the new location in "Start In" option (e.g D:\xyz)
7. Drag that icon and add/pin it in "Task Bar"

Comment: running ad administrator always goes to system 32 =(

Comment: making a copy of an answere even after 6 years should not be upvoted!

Comment: @Andrew You can change it by going to 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runas\command 
and then changing default directory arguments in after cmd.exe \C path of exe

Answer (score 8):

On Windows Start Menu, right click on Command Prompt.

Click on "Properties".

"Command Prompt Properties" dialog box opens.

Edit the field "Start in " to a location where you want to start the command prompt.

Example: Chand %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% to D:\PersonalPrograms.

Next time when you start command prompt the start up directory will be D:\PersonalPrograms

Answer (score 6):

Bit late but ignore the registry mods.
Simply change the shortcut target to:

```
cmd /k "command"
```

i.e.

```
cmd /k "cd\myStartUpFolder"
```

Voila!

Comment: This is simple, non invasive and works great. Most of the other answers do not work with Run As Admin setting, which I have checked on my shortcut.

Comment: In case you have other commands you want to enter you can combine them using the & or && operator but the whole thing must be enclosed in quotes.  In case your desired folder is on another drive you can also use the /D option for the "cd" command to switch immediately to the drive.e.g. `cmd /k ""C:\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & cd /d d:\projects"`

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work for me.  I've tried this both under Win7 64bit and Vista 32.

I'm using the below commandline to add this capability.

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "IF x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:)"

Comment: This is not an answer. If you need to ask the author something, post a comment. If you have a question, then post your own.

Comment: Now that this has been edited, it's a great answer. But I prefer less quotes: `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "if x%COMSPEC%==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /d d:\)"`. Command line solutions FTW!

Comment: To go to your profiles homefolder on your computer, use `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "if x%COMSPEC%==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /d %USERPROFILE%)"`

Comment: To update the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH variable with your local home folder, and then go to that folder, use `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "if x%COMSPEC%==x%CMDCMDLINE% (set "HOMEDRIVE=%USERPROFILE:~,2%" & set "HOMEPATH=%USERPROFILE:~2%" & cd /d %USERPROFILE%)"`

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to make a `cmd` shortcut, then change the shortcut's *"Start in"* directory to the one you want to start with.

[image: described_image]

Answer (score 2):

On windows 7:

1. Do a search for "cmd" on your Windows computer

   2. right-click cmd and left click "Pin to start menu" (Alternatively, right-click cmd - click copy and then paste to your desktop )
   3. right-click the cmd in your start menu or on your desktop (depending on choice 2 above) - left click properties
   4. inside the "start in" text box paste the location of your default start directory
   5. Press Apply and OK

Every time you click on the cmd in your start menu or your desktop shortcut, the CMD will open in your default location

Comment: From a usability perspective this is the best option. It also doesn't screw up the rest of your environment or require knowing some special key!

Answer (score 1):

changing shortcut under Windows System on 8.1 worked for me - another thing I found is that 'Start In:' WORKS when Advanced -> Run as admin is UNCHECKED, however, if CHECKED, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

string: Autorun
value: cd /d %~dp0

all bat files will run from the bat file location

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It actually seems that editing the file shortcut breaks the  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> key shortcut. (Moral of the story: only change system files you know how to fix! Eventually after a Windows update it repaired itself.)

What I ended up doing is creating a new customized Command Prompt shortcut in the start folder and pinned to the taskbar that I launch instead of `cmd.exe`

---

As other answers point out, changing the registry Autorun cmd start location is a bad idea because it silently will break other programs that shell out for tasks, like Visual Studio Code.

You should just change whatever shortcut you use to open cmd to have a Start In entry.

If you use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> to launch cmd, you can edit the Start In for

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\02 - Command Prompt.lnk"
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it + bonus.

Start `cmd` with administrator rights, the default directory for the prompt will be `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

I created a bat file in that directory (`notes.bat`)
Opened it with notepad and wrote the following lines. Each line is followed with a comment which should not be added to the bat file.

```
@echo off

prompt $S$CYourNamel$F$S$G$S 
/* This is a comment, do not include it in the bat file - above line will make the prompt look like  (YourName) > */

cd C:\Your_favorite_directory
/* This is a comment, do not include it in the bat file - above line will navigate you to your desired directory */
```

Saved the file and that was it. 
Now when You open `cmd` with admin rights, just write: `notes` or `notes.bat`
and it will execute the `notes.bat` file with desired changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to regedit ( go to search and type regedit)
2. expand "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" node
3. under HKEY_CURRENT_USER node expand "software" node
4. under software node expand "microsoft" node
5. under microsoft node click on "Command Processor"
6. path looks like this : "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"

[it looks something like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27v2Z.png)

7. if you do not see "Autorun" String Value
8. Right Click - New - Expandable String Value, and rename it to Autorun
9. double click on "Autorun" 
   10.enter this value path format:
10. "CD/d C:\yourfoldername\yoursubfoldername"

Answer (score 0):

type

```
cmd.exe /k cd c:/
```

in a text file and save as cmd.bat Clicking this file does the trick. You can pin it to the start menu as well.

To start in a partitioned drive (e.g. D), use

```
cmd.exe /k d:
```

Answer (score 0):

My default dir was system32 when starting CMD. 
I then created a batch file in that directory to change dir to the one I was after.

This caused me to always call that bat when starting CMD every time.
So I made a reg file & put this inside:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="cd C:\\Users\\Me\\SomeFolder"
```

After saving it, I opened the file, clicked ok to merge with registry, and since then every time I open CMD, I get my dir

Answer (score 0):

In the new Windows Terminal, you can click Settings and edit the line "startingDirectory" to achieve something similar.

Please note, however, that this changes the default startup directory only in Windows Terminal, and not for the command prompt globally.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) and [configure a starting directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#starting-directory).
Partial `settings.json`:

```
{
    // Make changes here to the cmd.exe profile.
    "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
    "name": "Command Prompt",
    "commandline": "cmd.exe",
    "hidden": false,
    "startingDirectory": "C:\\DEV"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` is no longer valid.

The new key is here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Change "Autorun" to "CD /d C:\YourFolder" (without double quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Keep the opening of the command prompt clean.  Avoid editing the registry key and adding an Autorun, it may come back to bite you.
Create a simple batch file and save it in the C:\Windows or C:\Windows\System32 folder.   I call mine !.bat (exclamation mark).  It has the following commands:

@echo off
c:
cd \
cls
whoami

It goes to the folder where I need to work, clears the screen and tells me what security context I'm in.

Answer (score -1):

"start in directory" command

```
cmd /K cd C:\WorkSpace
```

but if WorkSpace happens to be on different than C drive, console will be launched in default folder and then you still need to put D: to change drive
To avoid this use cd with -d parameter

```
cmd /K cd -d D:\WorkSpace
```

create a shortcut and your fixed ;)

Answer (score -1):

hi if you want cmd to automatically open when the machine starts up you can place the cmd.exe executable in the startup folder(just search for startup and place a shortcut of cmd.exe there)

Answer (score -3):

regedit worked great.  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Command` Processor, all you have to do is change the AutoRun key value, which is already set to wherever you are currently getting dumped into to a new value in the format of:

```
cd /d <drive:path>

for c:\, that would be cd /d c:\
for junk, that would be cd d/ c:\junk
```

its very simple, even a novice thats never used regedit should be able to figure it out.  if not, go to the c:\prompt and just type in regedit, then follow the path to the key.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, but repeating another answer is not an answer itself.