# Windows 7: cmd.exe: setting startup directory (in a link to cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, directory

I am running Windows 7 and when I run cmd.exe I want it to start up
in a directory named C:\foo\bar. I remember being able to create a
link to this executable on the desktop and right clicking somewhere
to set the startup menu of the cmd.exe command prompt by filling
out a field in a transient window, but I cannot find it. I have
found the following argument which however seems more complicated.
I want to set the startup directory for cmd.exe via a popup window.

[Changing default startup directory for command prompt in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

as mentioned by the other posters already:
the regular approach is to edit the shortcut's properties and fill the field labled "start in". simple as that.

however, for some reason this has no effect on UAC enabled systems if *at the same time* you also enable the "run as administrator" checkbox in the advanced properties of the shortcut.

[image]

a solution is to put everything in the "target" field of the shortcut:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /K cd /d "E:\My Folder" & sometest.bat
```

when running on 64bit and you want to explicitly start the 32bit flavour of the command prompt:

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K cd /d "E:\My Folder" & sometest.bat
```

for additional information on the command line parameters used above see:
`cmd.exe /?`
`cd.exe /?`

Comment: What is the `/d` switch doing?

Comment: /d tells cd to use the full path and change drive letters as needed.  So instead of doing something like "prompt> d:" to get to the D drive and then doing "prompt> cd somedir_on_d" you can just "cd /d d:\somedir_on_d"...really handy once you know it's there.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need! This should be the chosen answer!

Comment: The *reason* it doesn't work is `Start in` merely sets the working directory, but UAC does not inherit working directly specifically to prevent attacks on the search path (note that `sudo` does the same thing by default on *nix).

Comment: How do I execute another command after `/K cd /d "E:\My Folder" ` ? Such as I want to start at some place and enter a python virtualenv,  which need extra command `activate py3`

Answer (score 7):

When you create a shortcut to cmd.exe, you can open the shortcut properties and find under *Shortcut* tab the *Starts in* option that will tell `cmd.exe` where to start, like here:

[image: Command Prompt Shortcut Properties]

Answer (score 4):

Open the properties of a shortcut to `cmd` and set the directory there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Shortcut Target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe cd /d %~dp0
```

Which will start `cmd.exe` in the shortcut's folder.