# .bashrc equivalent for windows cmd shell?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Is there a .bashrc like file that Windows cmd shell reads on start-up?

I'd like to set a shorter prompt, the default prompt shows the full path to the current directory and it gets messy when I descend down several levels of sub-directories. Currently, I'm manually calling the `PROMPT` command whenever the displayed path gets too long. It'll be nice to set it automatically.

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: @Superdrac: I don't think so. I'm looking for a solution where in I can set the PROMPT in a startup file (similar to an `export PS1=...` statement in .bashrc).

Comment: Newer answers have been posted that affect cmd.exe directly, meaning you can launch cmd.exe and get desired results instead of launching it through a separate file. SETX especially is a quick and easy way and it should be accepted so that other people looking for an answer find it first and can solve their problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a batch file to launch a cmd prompt:

```
@echo off
cmd /k prompt $g
```

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to SETX, you can create a batch file that will effectively act as .bashrc. Then create a registry key called *AutoRun* under *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor* and set the path to that file as a value.

Answer (score 5):

You can control the command line prompt either with the *command* `PROMPT` or with the *variable* `PROMPT`. For an example, the following two commands have the same effect:

1. ```
   PROMPT $G
   ```
2. ```
   SET PROMPT=$G
   ```

Ultimately, however, it is the variable that determines the prompt's formatting, and when you are using the command, it merely sets the variable for you.

With that in mind, you could just assign a *default* value to the `PROMPT` variable using the `SETX` command:

```
SETX PROMPT "$G"
```

From now on, even after you reboot the system, every new<sup>1</sup> CMD session's prompt will be formatted as `$G` by default, until you change the variable again or reset it (globally). You can globally reset a variable by assigning it an empty value like this:

```
SETX PROMPT ""
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The CMD session that issues the `SETX` is not affected.</sub>