# Java: Storing project files so program is called without listing directory in console using javac

Tags: java

Is it possible to save .java file in a directory so that I do not need to list or include the path when using console.

Currently my projects are in the following location: `N:\jdev\lab` and each time I run the console I must change the directory from Windows default.

Here is a very basic example:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32> n:

N:\> cd jdev\lab

N:\jdev\lab> javac ConvertGallonToLiterCaller.java

N:\jdev\lab> java ConvertGallonToLiterCaller

Enter number of gallon(s) to convert: 500
Result: 500.0 gallons is equals to 1892.7 liters

N:\jdev\lab> exit
```

I would rather do something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32> javac ConvertGallonToLiterCaller.java
```

Comment: Without putting your java files in the folder where your command prompt starts, I'm assuming?

Comment: Well, I at least need the project to be in it's own folder for organization sake.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://superuser.com/questions/49575/change-to-default-start-folder-for-windows-xp-command-prompt) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7)? Or do you not want to change your startup location? I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding you... Are you asking for a way to get `cmd` to automatically search a particular folder for a file, similar to adding something to the PATH variable?

Comment: No I think I need it to start listing my project directory, like your suggestion, I was just looking in several books and noticed that the authors did not list directories and was wondering how was that possible? I am assuming I will have to switch the directory to run other things? Having the console open to a default directory where my project is; is not a bad idea.

Comment: Perfect, I used the first solution. Now when I open the console, it's right there. I was under the impression that I could save the files in one of those JDK folders. - Thanks

Comment: No problem! I was looking around to see if you can configure how to get Windows to look for things for arguments, since PATH configures where to look for executables, but wasn't finding anything. Glad to hear that you got something working though.

Comment: I'm not sure how the book authors did their things. I assume they just cut out all the boring things; haven't seen or heard of anything that would let you specify a file without a relative path or anything, at least.