# Node.Js windows command prompt change C:\ path to test directory instead

Tags: node.js, cmd, path, directory

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to change the Node.Js command prompt default path = C:\users...> (default when the prompt is launched) or C:\Windows\System (if launched with administrator privileges), to the location of the folder where i'm working.

Normally I have been doing C:\users..> cd C:\xampp\htdocs..... to navigate to the test folder and run test. Although once the command prompt is closed it reverts back to C:\users...>.

To achieve what I want I came across using Z:>C:\xampp\htdocs\projects.... but this returns access denied with or without administrator privileges. Even if I try C:>C:\xampp\htdocs\projects.... still get the Access Denied for some unknown reason. To be honest I don't know what Z:> or C:> will result.

Is it possible to change the default prompt path to the path of the directory I am working in so that every time command prompt is launched it goes to that directory? In this case C:\xampp\htdocs\projects.... instead of C:\users...>

Comment: IDK what a "node.is command prompt" is or how you define your current directory, but if the node executable is in your path, it should just be a matter of opening your shell to the correct directory, which probably makes this a general computing question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a general windows CMD question. Simply change the start up directory for CMD. [See this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Once you're in that directory, you should be able to run the `node` command as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your default nodejs installation folder for a file called nodevars.bat. Here is my path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat
```

Open this and look towards the bottom--the line I needed was on the very bottom. Here is the line from the git master:

`if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"`

I changed mine to

`if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "C:\Users\David\Desktop\work\J\math"`

And now I am happier.

I had the same question, today, 4/11/22, and DuckDuckGo provided this as the number one result for my query. Since the question appears to be unanswered, I will try for those who might show up later.