# %CMDCMDLINE% special var magically altered, although there's no assignment

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt

After applying this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4900046/447503) on my system, I noticed that clicking on `.bat` files now results:

```
"/c" is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

And in an attempt to fix it I tried to replace the quotes in `%CMDCMDLINE%` in the `IF` expression using the `Environment variable substitution`. And then I noticed something strange. Here's my test batch file:

```
@echo off
echo _%CMDCMDLINE%_
echo _%CMDCMDLINE:"=_%_
echo _%CMDCMDLINE%_
pause
```

and this is its output:

```
_C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\cygwin\opt\openconnect64\rek.bat" "_
_C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c __C:\cygwin\opt\openconnect64\rek.bat_ __
_C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c __C:\cygwin\opt\openconnect64\rek.bat_ __
```

As you can see, although there's no assignment, the variable is altered. This doesn't occur for other environment variables with the same value.

Comment: Instead of `IF /I x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)` better use `IF /I "%COMSPEC%"=="%CMDCMDLINE:"= %" (cd /D c:\)`

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, don't know where cmd.exe stores the automatic variables, looks like this is a pointer issue. Successive runs in an open window show the altered content, newly started cmd windows begin with double quotes.

Comment: basin, this site is designed to provide answers to questions with problematic code. You do not appear to have asked a question and you do not appear to have suggested that there is a problem with your code. The question is therefore either simply making a statement, which means you need a blog, or seeking reference material, which means you need a different site because requests of that type are off-topic here. Please therefore [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50995536/edit) to make it on-topic or delete it and find a more appropriate platform; thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the [well known `cmdcmdline` effect](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4312).
It's the only variable that shows this very useful behaviour.

It's useful, as it's a good possibility to examine how the parser works.
Like the question, if the parser expand variables after a `REM` or label?
Btw. It also works the same way with delayed expansion

```
@echo off
echo %CMDCMDLINE%
REM %CMDCMDLINE:C:=1#%
: %CMDCMDLINE:"=X%

echo %CMDCMDLINE%
```

It should be avoided to make the cmdcmdline variable longer than the initial length, as this can crash cmd.exe

Comment: When a variable read is detected by the parser the `GetEnvVar` function is called. Here a buffer is allocated to store the data returned from the `GetEnvironmentVariableW` API if the variable exists and a pointer to this buffer is returned. If the variable doesn't exist the list of dynamic vars is checked. For `CMDCMDLINE`, the `GetCommandLineW ` is called and the returned pointer to the command-line string for the current process is returned by `GetEnvVar` **instead** of the pointer to the internal buffer. As the substring/replace operations are executed inplace over pointed data, ...

Comment: @MCND Thanks for your debug session. I made only black box testings, but it's good to known the real reason for the problem